# Push data to existing array group

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering how I can push data onto an existing array.  At the moment, I am creating a data array like so

```
$data = [
    1 => [
        "title" => "TITLE ONE",
        "groups" => [[
            "Some question?" => $submission->answerOne ? "Yes": "No",
            "Some question?" => $submission->answerTwo ? "Yes": "No",
            "Some question?" => $submission->answerThree,
            "Some question?" => $submission->answerFour ? "Yes": "No",
            "Some question?" => $submission->answerFive ? "Yes": "No",
        ]]
    ], "title" => "TITLE TWO",
        "groups" => [[
            "Title" => $submission->title,
        ]]
    ]
];
```

I have removed a lot of sections, as well as the proper relationships, just to reduce the code.  So a `$submission` can have many addresses, and I want to add these to the groups for TITLE TWO.

So under this, I am doing a loop

```
foreach ($data as $sectionIndex => $sectionData) {
    if ($sectionData["title"] === "TITLE TWO") {
        foreach ($submission->addresses as $address) {
            $sectionData["groups"] = [
                "House Number" => $address->houseNumber
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

If I output `$address->houseNumber` I can see the correct data.  However, this is not being added to my $data array.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

```
Current Output

&array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(23) "TITLE TWO"
    ["groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(16) {
        ["Title"]=>
        string(2) "Dr"
      }
      ["House Number"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(19) "35"
      }
    }
  }
}

Expected output

&array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(23) "TITLE TWO"
    ["groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(16) {
        ["Title"]=>
        string(2) "Dr"
        ["House Number"]=>
        string(19) "35"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: $sectionData["groups"] change $sectionData["groups"][]

Answer (score 2):

To actually modify the element you have to use a reference in the foreach:

```
foreach ($data as $sectionIndex => &$sectionData) {
```

The key is in the `&` before `$sectionData`.

You also have an issue in your second foreach loop, for every iteration you are overriding the previous value. Your code should be something along those lines:

```
foreach ($data as $sectionIndex => $sectionData) {
    if ($sectionData["title"] === "TITLE TWO") {
        foreach ($submission->addresses as $address) {
            $sectionData["groups"]["House Number"][] = $address->houseNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work well, thanks.  Only issue I see is that it is adding it to element 1 for the groups section.  Is it possible to get it in with the other data in the group?

Comment: What are your input and expected output? It's not super clear from your question and the answer will depend on it.

Comment: I added an update of where I am trying to get the house numbers to go, thanks

Comment: Then the code provided in my answer should do the trick. What should `House Number` be? An array? If so then yeah, this will work.

Comment: Sorry, provided another edit which shows the current output vs the expected output.  So House Number shouldnt be its own element, but an element part of the existing groups array

Comment: But what if you have multiple addresses in `$submission->addresses`?

Comment: Yes, but they should all be added to that section, if possible

Comment: But this is only possible if `House Number ` is an array, which is the output that you currently have, no?

Comment: No, because I am looping $submission->addresses which means they will be strings

Comment: Think I have achieved it with  $sectionData["groups"][0]["Date moved"] =